# Creating firefox add ons

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have written some application in c# .net and I want it to be able be called from Firefox like an add-on.
Add some button in Firefox menu and when it pressed my application is launched.

Is it possible to be done ? If so can you refer me to some tutorial how those things are done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET cannot be used to write extensions for FireFox. You could [build an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension) which runs your .NET application as a separate process.

Comment: What platform i should use in my case ?

Comment: @Night Walker: Firefox only supports one platform for its extensions - XUL. XUL uses XML and JavaScript to implement the extension. As Darin says, the extension can run your .NET app as a separate process. But beware that this will be less portable.