# Which web browsers allow me to write addons/extensions using C# and .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

Which web browsers allow me to write addons/extensions using C# and .NET Framework?

Comment: As i know it can be done only for IE. HTML & JS are used to write extensions for Chrome & FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is there for sure

and well html and javascript used in asp.NET will help you work it for chrome

the C# or VB part in ASP.NET sure could be used for serverside process with extensions of any browser

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about other browsers, But for Firefox:
[How to write FireFox extension with Visual Studio using C# programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680965/how-to-write-firefox-extension-with-visual-studio-using-c-programming-language)
And AFAIK:

> .NET cannot be used to write extensions for FireFox. You could build an extension which runs your .NET application as a separate process.

from: [Creating firefox add ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117095/creating-firefox-add-ons)

Answer (score 0):

Using Native Client, one could write a plug-in for Chrome that targets Mono.

http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#Google_Native_Client_Support

Of course Mono supports C#...

I'll add that Native Client isn't the same thing as a browser extension or add-on.  It's more akin to the Netscape Plug-in architecture or ActiveX controls.

http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/